# merge objects into one and override the existing object - javascript es6

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have an one object which contains multiple objects like this below:

```
const productFields = {
    category_id: {
        key: 'category_id',
        label: 'Category',
        uri: '/products/category',
        value: '',
        items: []
    },
    product_name: {
        key: 'product_name',
        label: 'Product Name',
        value: '',
        items: []
    }
};
```

Now I want to add one more property into product_name object. I am doing the normal way using spread operator.

```
const newNameFields = { 
    ...productFields.product_name, 
    uri:`/products/${this.$route.params.id}/category/${this.categoryId}`
};
```

Now, I am creating new object like this:

```
const newField = Object.assign({}, category_id: productFields.category_id , product_name: newNameFields);
```

But, is there any good different logic to do that without initialize that many variables and single shot? It is kind of lame logic I am doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple spreads to add the property `uri` to `product_name`:

```js
const productFields = {"category_id":{"key":"category_id","label":"Category","uri":"/products/category","value":"","items":[]},"product_name":{"key":"product_name","label":"Product Name","value":"","items":[]}};
const paramsId = 'paramsId';
const categoryId = 'categoryId';

const newProductFields = {
  ...productFields, // spread the base object
  product_name: { // override product_name
    ...productFields.product_name, // add the original product_name
    uri: `/products/${paramsId}/category/${categoryId}` // add the property
  }
};

console.log(newProductFields);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the property if you are ok to mutate the original object.

```
const productFields = {

    category_id: {
        key: 'category_id',
        label: 'Category',
        uri: '/products/category',
        value: '',
        items: []
    },
    product_name: {
        key: 'product_name',
        label: 'Product Name',
        value: '',
        items: []
    }

};

productFields.product_name.x = 'new value'
```

If you do not want to mutate the original object you will need to clone the properties and add a new one like you are doing with `Spread syntax` or `Object.assign`

Comment: Yes 2nd approach is preferable. But, i want it in one line approach. Is there any workaround make my logic more user preferable?

Comment: what about the first approach?